# Simplifying a function with absolute value and two variables

Tags: absolute-value

I am trying to simplify the following

$ f(\alpha, \beta)= \big|1-(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\frac{|\beta-\alpha|}{2})\big|-2 \big|1-\alpha-(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\frac{|\beta-\alpha|}{2})\big|+ |\alpha-1| -\beta+|\beta-\alpha|-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{|\beta-\alpha|}{2}\leq 0$

I have the following conditions: $\beta-\alpha<0$, $\alpha-1>0$

I got that the function can be simplified to

$$f(\alpha,\beta)=\big|1-\alpha \big|- 2\big|1-2\alpha\big| +\alpha -2\beta-1=0\rightarrow \alpha+\beta \geq 0$$

Is my analysis correct?

Under a different set of conditions: $\beta-\alpha<0$, $\alpha-1<0$

I have that 
$$f(\alpha,\beta)= \big|1-\alpha \big|- 2\big|1-2\alpha\big| + 1-2 \beta-\alpha=0 \rightarrow \beta \geq 0$$
Is my analysis for this set of conditions correct ?